# Parsing values from string array

Tags: f#

I am trying to create a save/load function for 2d objects that has been drawn into a form.

```
type circle = { X : int; Y : int; Diameter : int; Brush : Brush}
type Square = { X : int; Y : int; Length : int; Height: int; Brush : Brush}
```

When i create the object i put them into 2 lists 1 for each type.
My initial thought was to read and write these objects to a textfile, see below:

```
saveFile.Click.Add(fun _ ->
 for c in listOfCircles do 
   myfile.WriteLine("Circle," + c.X.ToString() + "," + c.Y.ToString() + "," + c.Diameter.ToString() + "," + c.Brush.ToString())
 for s in listOfSquares do
   myfile.WriteLine("Square," + s.X.ToString() + "," + s.Y.ToString() + "," + s.Height.ToString() + "," + s.Length.ToString() + "," + s.Brush.ToString())
 myfile.Close() // close the file
```

And in the textfile it looks like this

```
Circle,200,200,50,System.Drawing.SolidBrush
Square,50,55,45,55,System.Drawing.SolidBrush
```

From here i want to read these values and then be able to parse them and recreate the objects by adding the objects the lists and redraw them.

```
let readCircle =
  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines path
  |> Array.choose (fun s ->
    match s.Split ',' with
    | [|x; y ; z ; b ; _|] when x = "Circle" -> Some (y, z, b)
    | _ -> None )

let readSquare =  
  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines path
  |> Array.choose (fun s ->
    match s.Split ',' with
    | [|x; y ; z ; b ; a ; _|] when x = "Square" -> Some (y, z, b, a)
    | _ -> None )
```

These functions gives me

```
val readCircle : (string * string * string) [] = [|("200", "200", "50")|]
val readSquare : (string * string * string * string) [] = [|("50", "55", "45", "55")|]
```

The problem i have now is im not sure how to obtain the values from the array. Beneath is example with multiple circles.

```
val readCircle : (string * string * string) [] =  [|("200", "200", "50"); ("200", "200","50")|]
```

Any ideas or comments about how to go from here/how to resolve this issue is very appreciated! Question summary: how could i get the values from the array and put them in for example my already created add functions, see below:

```
 listOfCircles.Add({ X = 200; Y = 200; Diameter = 50; Brush = Brushes.Black})
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. But assuming you need to convert your array of values to a list of shapes, you could use `values |> Seq.map createCircle |> Seq.toList`.

Comment: I want to get the values from the array and put them into the listOfCircles.Add function, see the edited bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the arrays of string tuples you have using `Array.map`, e.g.

```
[|("200", "200", "50"); ("200", "200","50")|]
|> Array.map (fun (x,y,d) -> {X = int32 x; Y = int32 y; Diameter = int32 d; Brush = Brushes.Black})
```

It might be a bit clearer if you converted to `circle` or `square` as you parsed the file, then you would have an array of `circle` or an array of `square` that you can add directly to your lists.

```
let readCircle =
  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines path
  |> Array.choose (fun s ->
    match s.Split ',' with
    | [|t; x; y; d; _|] when t = "Circle" -> 
        Some {X = int32 x; Y = int32 y; Diameter = int32 d; Brush = Brushes.Red}
    | _ -> None )
```

But... if you wanted to make larger changes, you could use discriminated unions to represent your shapes, they would then share a common type of `Shape` and you could parse circles and squares in the same function.

```
type Shape = 
| Circle of X : int * Y : int * Diameter : int * Brush : Brush
| Square of X : int * Y : int * Length : int * Height: int * Brush : Brush 

let readShapes (data: string array) =
  data
  |> Array.choose (fun s ->
    match s.Split ',' with
    | [|t; x; y; d; _|] when t = "Circle" -> 
        Some (Circle(X = int32 x, Y = int32 y, Diameter = int32 d, Brush = Brushes.Red))
    | [|t; x; y; l; h; _|] when t = "Square" -> 
        Some (Square(X = int32 x, Y = int32 y, Length = int32 l, Height = int32 h, Brush = Brushes.Red))
    | _ -> None )

let listOfShapes = ResizeArray<_>()

let testInput = """
Circle,200,200,50,System.Drawing.SolidBrush
Square,50,55,45,55,System.Drawing.SolidBrush"""

testInput.Split('\n') // System.IO.File.ReadAllLines path
|> readShapes
|> Array.iter (listOfShapes.Add)
```

Which would result in

```
val it : System.Collections.Generic.List<Shape> =
  seq
    [Circle (200,200,50,System.Drawing.SolidBrush {Color = Color [Red];});
     Square (50,55,45,55,System.Drawing.SolidBrush {Color = Color [Red];})]
```

You could then use pattern matching to draw each type of shape

```
let drawShape shape =
    match shape with
    | Circle(x,y,d,b) -> 
        printfn "Pretend I just drew a circle at %d,%d with diameter %d." x y d
    | Square(x,y,l,h,b) -> 
        printfn "Pretend I just drew a rectangle at %d,%d that was %d long and %d high." x y l h

listOfShapes |> Seq.iter drawShape
```

Giving

```
Pretend I just drew a circle at 200,200 with diameter 50.
Pretend I just drew a rectangle at 50,55 that was 45 long and 55 high.
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your goal, this is how I would go about it. I've only implemented `Circle`; you'll need to modify it to handle `Square`.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Drawing
open System.IO

let memoize f =
  let cache = Dictionary()
  fun key ->
    match cache.TryGetValue(key) with
    | true, value -> value
    | _ ->
      let value = f key
      cache.Add(key, value)
      value

let getBrush =
  memoize (fun name -> typeof<Brushes>.GetProperty(name).GetValue(null) :?> SolidBrush)

type Circle = 
  { X : int
    Y : int
    Diameter : int
    Brush : SolidBrush } with
  override this.ToString() = 
    sprintf "Circle,%d,%d,%d,%s" this.X this.Y this.Diameter this.Brush.Color.Name
  static member Parse(s: string) =
    match s.Split(',') with
    | [|"Circle";x;y;diameter;brushName|] -> {X=int x; Y=int y; Diameter=int diameter; Brush=getBrush brushName}
    | _ -> invalidArg "s" "Cannot parse string"

let writeShapesToFile fileName shapes =
  File.WriteAllLines(fileName, Seq.map (sprintf "%O") shapes)

let readShapesFromFile fileName =
  File.ReadAllLines(fileName) |> Array.map Circle.Parse
```

Also,  you might consider using a class hierarchy instead of records since much of the structure and behavior of `Circle` and `Square` are shared.

Answer (score 1):

This is fun - I approached it in a totally different way than Daniel (but I agree with him that you classes might be a better approach for your shapes).  Instead, I took advantage of discriminated unions (and there are better ways to do this - more later):

First, I define a type for a list of parameters for making a shape:

```
type Parameter =
    | Label of string
    | Number of int
```

Now let's convert a string to a parameter:

```
let toParameter s =
    match Int32.TryParse(s) with
    | (true, i) -> Number(i)
    | (_, _) -> Label(s)
```

Now to convert a list of strings to a list of Parameter:

```
let stringListToParameterList stringlist = stringlist |> List.map(function s -> toParameter s)
```

Now to convert a comma-separated string to a list of string:

```
let commastringToList (s:string) = s.Split(',') |> Array.toList
```

OK - great - let's define your records and a master Shape:

```
type circlerec = { X : int; Y : int; Diameter : int; Brush : Brush}
type squarerec = { X : int; Y : int; Length : int; Height: int; Brush : Brush}
type Shape =
    | Circle of circlerec
    | Square of squarerec
```

With this we need a way to make a Shape from a parameter list.  This is brute force, but it reads well enough:

```
let toShape list =
    match list with
    | Label("Circle") :: Number(x) :: Number(y) :: Number(diam) :: Label(colorName) :: [] ->
        Circle({X = x; Y = y; Diameter = diam; Brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromName(colorName)); })
    | Label("Circle") :: rest -> raise <| new ArgumentException("parse error:expected Circle num num num color but got " + list.ToString())
    | Label("Square") :: Number(x) :: Number(y) :: Number(length) :: Number(height) :: Label(colorName) :: [] ->
        Square({X = x; Y = y; Length = length; Height = height; Brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromName(colorName)); })
    | Label("Square") :: rest -> raise <| new ArgumentException("parse error:expected Square num num num num color but got " + list.ToString())
    | _ -> raise <| new ArgumentException("parse error: unknown shape: " + list.ToString())
```

It's dense, but I'm using F#'s pattern matching to spot the various parameters for each shape.  Note that you could now do things like have `Square,x,y,size,colorName` in your file and make a Square where Length and Height are equal to size by just adding in the pattern.

Finally comes the piece de resistance, converting your file into shapes:

```
let toShapes path =
    System.IO.File.ReadAllLines path |> Array.toList |>
        List.map(function s -> s |> commastringToList |>
        stringListToParameterList |> toShape)
```

which maps every line in the file to a list of string which then maps each line to a shape, but piping the comma string to the list converter and then through the parameter list and then to a shape.

Now where this is bad is that the error checking is pretty horrid and that the Parameter type should really include `Pigment of Color`, which would allow you to look at the string that comes in and if it's valid Color name, map it to a Pigment else a Label.